# How to edit a final class field in a method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to edit my fields in a method like that :

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget{
  Test({this.firstField, this.secondField});

  final String firstField ;
  final String secondField ;
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return null;
  }


  editField( field, newValue){
    //edit any field of the class in a single function here
  }
}
```

If I use `widget.firstField` as first parameter of my method I will be able to edit it locally ( in the method ) but not the field.

Comment: you can directly use firstField variable don't require to use with widget

Comment: why you are passing this as parameter, use a global variable.

Comment: I'm passing this as a parameter because I'm using the class as a route on which I edit the field and then get it back on the first route using `Navigator.pop(context, [firstField, secondField])`